# Is there a way to get list of all available projects on google code?

Tags: list, google-code, listings

Like in title, I would like to fetch a list of all available projects on Google Code, best if it can be list + project short description, only this, nothing more is needed.

Is it can be done in an automatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list hosted projects via category (platform), and/or further drill down with a search, at the link below.

[Google Code Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/)

Comment: I would like to do it more API friendly without curl or other things, to save this list in DB, but if no more possibilities will show up, I'll end up with this

Answer (score 4):

The [FLOSSmole project](http://flossmole.org/) collects and publishes monthly data about all Google Code projects.

A listing of project info including project name and project summary is available.  For example here is a link to the dataset for November 2011:

- http://code.google.com/p/flossmole/downloads/detail?name=gcProjectInfo2011-Nov.txt.bz2

The file format is one project per line, with tab-delimited fields.  The first field is the project name and the 8th field is the project summary.  So assuming you use wget to grab the file...

```
wget http://code.google.com/p/flossmole/downloads/detail?name=gcProjectInfo2011-Nov.txt.bz2
bunzip2 gcProjectInfo2011-Nov.txt.bz2
cut -f 1,8 gcProjectInfo2011-Nov.txt
```

A couple of notes:

1. Google Code has over 200,000 projects, so even in summary form, this is a lot of data!
2. Obviously this is a snapshot of Google Code projects, not a live, real-time listing.  I'm not sure if one exists.