# How to list all public available projects on Google Code?

Tags: git, svn, github, web-crawler, google-code

As Google Code is closing ([Bidding farewell to Google Code](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html)), I am thinking of dumping **ALL Free-Licensed** projects to local disk (or migrate to Github if allowed by their licence), because although most projects will migrate themselves to Github etc., other valuable projects not maintained anymore will get lost due to Google's refusing to host a read-only Google Code for long.

[Is there a way to get list of all available projects on Google code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615316/) gives one answer to crawl the labels of ***Project Hosting of Google Code***. However, Google Code has so many projects (200,000 or more) that I can't list them all with default search engine, which will only give less than 1,000 items for every keyword. For example, you can only get the first 966 projects under label Python while you are expecting all 30,000, for instance, Python projects. And to obtain all labels is no easier than listing all projects at all.

[Is there a way to get list of all available projects on Google code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615316/) gives another solution ***FLOSSmole project***. But FLOSSmole stopped updating since Nov 2012 for Google Code. It is 2 more years later now.

So, apart from the two methods above, by what means can I list all public available projects on Google Code?
Moreover, what is the most efficient way to dump them?

Comment: so is this really a different question than [the one you linked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615316/is-there-a-way-to-get-list-of-all-available-projects-on-google-code)?

Comment: It is not really different from that one no, but both answers don't apply anymore. Best use is opening a bounty on the other question with `Current answers are outdated` to get new answers, but OP here can't do that

Comment: @eis What tim-castelijns said is just what I want to say. The two answers are both outdated(I have detailed the explanation), though the later one was useful in some way. And I can do nothing to them.